# Xamarin.forms giving "invalid cross thread access" Exception in windows8 emulator

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-8, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Xamarin.forms is working fine in android phones but in window8 emulator it is not loading image and giving invalid cross thread access exception.

I'm using [Embedded Image](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/) Technique, I'm storing all images in common folder and accessing from shared project.

snapshot of my project is as follows:

[image]

Error is As follows :

[image]

In window8 simulator images are not loading

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Something in a background thread is trying to modify a UI element, please attach the stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are updating a UI element on a non UI thread, you want to use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread, like so:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => MainPage.DisplayAlert("Boom", message, "Cancel"));
```